# how to upgrade existing network's composer runtime to a minor version while keeping existing data?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

could any one suggest how to upgrade existing network's composer runtime to a minor version (say from 0.12.0 to 0.14.2) while keeping existing data? my network is configured with persistent data; since network update only supports micro version upgrade, I tried runtime install then network start, as expected it fails and says the chaincode already exists (my-network.0.12.0); i can certainly use a new network name but then I'd start brand new and previous data does not exist in the new network. Thanks for any advices

Answer (score 0):

Currently it isn't possible. A minor version change usually means that there has been an incompatible change to the runtime and we don't have any migration path in place for existing data stored in world state.

Comment: thanks David for the explanation. it really helps. appreciated.